# How to set more than one cookie with Azure Functions?

Tags: node.js, cookies, azure-functions

When setting headers with Azure Functions, you pass an Object with the headerName as the key and the value as the header value.

However, when creating cookies each cookie needs its own "Set-Cookie" header, but an Object key needs to be unique. How should this be handled?

e.g. The following sets two object keys as "Set-Cookie"; which my IDE is blowing up as not possible.

```
context.res = {
          status: 200,
          headers: {
              "Content-Type": "text/html",
              "Set-Cookie": "a=b; Secure; httpOnly; Path=/",
              "Set-Cookie": "b=c="; Secure; httpOnly; Path=/",
              "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store"
          },
          body:
              '<HTML><BODY>RESPONSE</BODY></HTML>'
      };
context.done();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Set multiple cookies using the "[cookies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2#response-object)" property in an HTTP response object

Unfortunately, this is currently a bug (first brought up [in this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2737)). This isn't ideal, but here is a workaround you can use for now (note the additional white space in the "Set-Cookie "):

```
context.res = {
      status: 200,
      headers: {
          "Content-Type": "text/html",
          "Set-Cookie": "a=b; Secure; httpOnly; Path=/",
          "Set-Cookie ": "b=c="; Secure; httpOnly; Path=/",
          "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store"
      },
      body:
          '<HTML><BODY>RESPONSE</BODY></HTML>'
  };
context.done();
```

Comment: At the bottom of that GH thread Marie gives an [updated answer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2737#issuecomment-568037718): there's now a `context.res.cookies` property which is an array of cookie objects to be sent with response.

Comment: The workaround is not a solution
Running a Python function in VSC
'''
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core: Invalid non-ASCII or control character in header: 0x002
'''

Comment: This answer is definitely applicable for JavaScript/TypeScript functions. @vrdmr should be able to help with this question for Python functions! You can ask here too https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker

Answer (score 1):

You can set multiple cookies on a response object with the property "cookies", which takes an array of Cookie objects.

To know more about Cookie objects:- [Click Here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-nodejs-worker/blob/dev/types/public/Interfaces.d.ts#L120-L143)

```
var cookieExipre = new Date();
cookieExipre.setTime(
    cookieExipre.getTime() + 2 * 60 * 1000 // Cookie exipre in 2 minutes
);
context.res = {
    body: "Hello",
    status: 200,
    cookies: [
        {
            name: "cookie1",
            value: "cookie1",
            secure: true,
            httponly: true,
            path: "/",
            expires: cookieExipre,
            sameSite: "None",
        },
        {
            name: "cookie2",
            value: "cookie2",
            secure: isSecure,
            httponly: true,
            path: "/",
            expires: cookieExipre,
            sameSite: "None",
        },
    ],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This also applies to Python/Django
I did find the root cause for the bug
https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/2145

The cookies are stored in a Dict. As a result, multiple http response headers are not supported. I guess the JS implementation has the same issue.